# Using a loop to produce XML output?

Tags: jquery, xml, loops

I'm trying to use a select element to produce a dynamic output with jQuery and XML.  But when I get to the if statement, the XML each loop only uses the first ID on sandwiches. How do I make the if statement test each sandwich ID against the selected ID? Every time I run it, it only uses "TheItalian" ID for each of the four loops through.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandwiches</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css"/>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Nick's Sandwich Shop</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
            <section id="selection">
            <h2>Please select a sandwich</h2>
            <select id="selector">
                <option>Select One...</option>
                <option id="TheItalian">The Italian</option>
                <option id="BLTPlus1">BLT+1</option>
                <option id="TheBillyClub">The Billy Club</option>
                <option id="FrenchDip">French Dip</option>
            </select>
            </section>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#selector").change(function() {
                        var sandwichChoice = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "sandwiches.xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function(data){
                                var $xml = $(data);
                                var $sandwich = $xml.find("sandwich");
                                alert($sandwich.length);
                                $sandwich.each(function(){
                                    console.log($sandwich.attr("id"));
                                    console.log(sandwichChoice);
                                    if ($sandwich.attr("id" ) == sandwichChoice) {
                                        var $name = $(this).find("name");
                                        alert($name.text());
                                    };
                                });
                            }});
                        });
                    });

            </script>   
    </section>  
</body>
</html>
```

My XML data

```
<sandwiches>
    <sandwich id="TheItalian">
        <name>The Italian</name>
        <bread>Italian</bread>
        <meat>Black forest ham and salami</meat>
        <cheese>Provolone</cheese>
        <veggies>Lettuce, tomatoes, onions, and mild peppers</veggies>
        <dressing>Italian oil</dressing>
    </sandwich>
    <sandwich id="BLTPlus1">
        <name>BLT+1</name>
        <bread>Sourdough</bread>
        <meat>Bacon and more bacon</meat>
        <cheese>Cheddar</cheese>
        <veggies>Lettuce and tomatoes</veggies>
        <dressing>Spicy garlic mayo</dressing>
    </sandwich>
    <sandwich id="TheBillyClub">
        <name>The Billy Club</name>
        <bread>Rye</bread>
        <meat>Turkey, bacon and black forest ham</meat>
        <cheese>Cheddar and Swiss</cheese>
        <veggies>Lettuce, tomatoes, </veggies>
        <dressing>Honey mustard and mayo</dressing>
    </sandwich>
    <sandwich id="FrenchDip">
        <name>French Dip</name>
        <bread>Baguette</bread>
        <meat>Roast beef</meat>
        <cheese>Melted Cheddar</cheese>
        <veggies>Grilled onions</veggies>
        <dressing>Au jus</dressing>
    </sandwich>
</sandwiches>
```

Comment: Why $sandwich? I mean why are you using $ with a variable Just say `var sandwich = data.find("sandwich");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this revised jQ for your AJAX success callback:

```
success: function(xml){
    $(xml).find("sandwich").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("id" ) == sandwichChoice) {
            var $name = $(this).find("name");
            alert($name.text());
        };
    });
}
```

I believe the issue is this line...

```
if ($sandwich.attr("id")
```

...because `$sandwich` is a jQ collection of all the sandwich items in the XML, not a single sandwich.

Also, if you're not opposed/unable to use the "value" attribute on your <option> elements, selecting your 'sandwichChoice' would be easier with "value" attributes present:

```
$("#selector").change(function() {
    var sandwichChoice = $(this).val();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was probably missing something silly. Also, thank you for the suggestion on using val(), that does work better.